# Elasticsearch: Query to filter out specific documents based on field value and return count

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm trying to compose a query in Elasticsearch that filters out documents with a specific field value, and also returns the number of documents that has been filtered out as an aggregation.

What I have so far is below, however, with my solution it seems that the documents are filtered out first, then after the filtering, the count is performed, which is making it always be 0.

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must_not":[
            {
               "terms":{
                  "gender":[
                     "male"
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs":{
      "removed_docs_count":{
         "filter":{
            "term":{
               "gender":"male"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a query block, just `aggs` will provide you expected results.

```
{
   "aggs":{
      "removed_docs_count":{
         "filter":{
            "term":{
               "gender":"male"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but with only the aggs part the documents will not be filtered out, I will only get the count, right? I want the query to filter out the documents AND return the count ...

Comment: @alp123 if you look at your query, you can see first you are getting all the documents where `gender` is not equal to `male` and later on that documents you are running the `agss` where `gender` is `male` hence count 0. I didn't get what actually is your use case, you want to get the count of `male` gender correct? if you want to improve the performance you can have a `must` instead of `must_not` clause that way you will get the benefit of running aggs only on filtered documents.

Comment: Maybe it is not possible in the same query.. My ideal solution would be to filter out the documents and return the number of documents that have been filtered out as well, but that is maybe not possible.. Maybe I need to do as you suggested and do another to filter out ..

Comment: @alp123 if you can share your sample documents and expected results, it will be more clear, but if I correctly understand you just need the count of your filtered documents which you can easily get without extra query or `aggs`, you can just know it by using the `hits` "hits": {
"total": {
"value": 10000,
"relation": "gte"
},

Comment: @alp123 Elasticsearch by default shows max 10k with relation like `gte` in the example which means there were more hits, you can use `track_total_hits` to know the exact count.

Comment: After reading your comments, I think the easiest way will be to use the query you suggested first for the count and do two requests. I will mark your answer as the accepted one! Thanks!